# Why does iterating over IQueryable give the first value for each item in the result?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have a block of code that attempts to query some simple configuration parameters from a database. However, using the code below, as soon as I enumerate the result I get the first value for each item in the result:

```
var db = new ConfigurationServiceDataContext("Server=vsdcs022.aridev.lcl;Database=ConfigurationService;Trusted_Connection=True;");

var parameters =
    from configContents in db.ConfigurationContents
    where
        configContents.ConfigurationContextsTable.ConfigurationContextName == contextName &&
        configContents.ConfigurationSectionTable.ConfigurationSectionName == sectionName
    select configContents;

// print stuff for debugging purposes:
foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key = '{0}', value = '{1}'", parameter.ConfigurationKey, parameter.ConfigurationValue);
}

return parameters.ToDictionary(parameter => parameter.ConfigurationKey, parameter => parameter.ConfigurationValue);
```

If I print the results (before attempting to add them to a new dictionary) I get something like:

```
key = 'key1', value = 'value1'
key = 'key1', value = 'value1'
key = 'key1', value = 'value1'
```

But if I replace the **select** line with an anonymous type, it works just fine:

```
    select new { configContents.ConfigurationKey, configContents.ConfigurationValue };
```

With this anonymous type, I get the following result:

```
key = 'key1', value = 'value1'
key = 'key2', value = 'value2'
key = 'key3', value = 'value3'
```

I've researched this for a few hours now to no avail and while I could just call it good with the anonymous type, this is really bothering me. I have seen plenty of examples that suggest my first block of code should work just fine. I'm sure I'm doing something silly, I just can't see it!

Any ideas?

The following are the full details of the model I am using starting with the DataContext implementation:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using Ari.Core.ConfigurationService.LinqEntityClasses;

namespace Ari.Core.ConfigurationService
{
    class ConfigurationServiceDataContext : DataContext
    {
        public Table<ConfigurationContentsTable> ConfigurationContents;
        public Table<ConfigurationContextsTable> ConfigurationContexts;
        public Table<ConfigurationSectionsTable> ConfigurationSections;

        public ConfigurationServiceDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
    }
}
```

The core contents table is represented by my ConfigurationContentsTable entity class:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Ari.Core.ConfigurationService.LinqEntityClasses
{
    [Table(Name = "ConfigurationContents")]
    class ConfigurationContentsTable
    {
        private long _configurationContextId;
        private string _configurationKey;
        private string _configurationValue;
        private EntityRef<ConfigurationContextsTable> _configurationContextsTable;
        private EntityRef<ConfigurationSectionsTable> _configurationSectionsTable;

        public ConfigurationContentsTable()
        {
            _configurationContextsTable = new EntityRef<ConfigurationContextsTable>();
            _configurationSectionsTable = new EntityRef<ConfigurationSectionsTable>();
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationContextId", DbType = "BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true,
            IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public long ConfigurationContextId
        {
            get { return _configurationContextId; }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationKey")]
        public string ConfigurationKey
        {
            get { return _configurationKey; }
            set { _configurationKey = value; }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationValue")]
        public string ConfigurationValue
        {
            get { return _configurationValue; }
            set { _configurationValue = value; }
        }

        [Association(Storage = "_configurationContextsTable", OtherKey = "ConfigurationContextId")]
        public ConfigurationContextsTable ConfigurationContextsTable
        {
            get { return _configurationContextsTable.Entity; }
            set { _configurationContextsTable.Entity = value; }
        }

        [Association(Storage = "_configurationSectionsTable", OtherKey = "ConfigurationSectionId")]
        public ConfigurationSectionsTable ConfigurationSectionTable
        {
            get { return _configurationSectionsTable.Entity; }
            set { _configurationSectionsTable.Entity = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

The two associated tables are pretty simple and only exist for normalization purposes. They are represented as follows:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Ari.Core.ConfigurationService.LinqEntityClasses
{
    [Table(Name = "ConfigurationContexts")]
    class ConfigurationContextsTable
    {
        private long _configurationContextId;
        private string _configurationContextName;
        private EntityRef<ConfigurationContentsTable> _configurationContentsTable;

        public ConfigurationContextsTable()
        {
            _configurationContentsTable = new EntityRef<ConfigurationContentsTable>();
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationContextId", DbType = "BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true,
            IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public long ConfigurationContextId
        {
            get { return _configurationContextId; }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationContextName")]
        public string ConfigurationContextName
        {
            get { return _configurationContextName; }
            set { _configurationContextName = value; }
        }

        [Association(Storage = "_configurationContentsTable", ThisKey = "ConfigurationContextId")]
        public ConfigurationContentsTable ConfigurationContentsTable
        {
            get { return _configurationContentsTable.Entity; }
            set { _configurationContentsTable.Entity = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace Ari.Core.ConfigurationService.LinqEntityClasses
{
    [Table(Name = "ConfigurationSections")]
    class ConfigurationSectionsTable
    {
        private long _configurationSectionId;
        private string _configurationSectionName;
        private EntityRef<ConfigurationContentsTable> _configurationContentsTable;

        public ConfigurationSectionsTable()
        {
            _configurationContentsTable = new EntityRef<ConfigurationContentsTable>();
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationSectionId", DbType = "BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true,
            IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public long ConfigurationSectionId
        {
            get { return _configurationSectionId; }
        }

        [Column(Storage = "_configurationSectionName")]
        public string ConfigurationSectionName
        {
            get { return _configurationSectionName; }
            set { _configurationSectionName = value; }
        }

        [Association(Storage = "_configurationContentsTable", ThisKey = "ConfigurationSectionId")]
        public ConfigurationContentsTable ConfigurationContentsTable
        {
            get { return _configurationContentsTable.Entity; }
            set { _configurationContentsTable.Entity = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question! Please post your 'print the results' code (your code looks fine, at the moment my suspicion is that you're accessing a modified closure in the print code)

Comment: Can you post the code that prints the (incorrect) results?

Comment: Smells like modified closure.

Comment: I've added the logic I used to enumerate/print the values to the first code block.

Comment: @Jason, the problem is described in the second sentence of my post. I then go on to detail the problem with examples. Not sure what you're talking about. Thanks.

Comment: @Sam, Sorry, I misread. Shouldn't go on SO before making coffee.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am using Resharper v7 and it's not complaining about access to a modified closure.

Comment: post your model - what's the `ConfigurationContextsTable` etc. - also the where the `ConfigurationKey` is etc. - that's where the problem is

Comment: I suspect you are right NSGaga. I have posted the full contents of my model for review. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more digging and reviewing of my code, I found two problems that, when corrected, yield the expected result.

First, in my ConfigurationContentsTable entity class my PK field was configured to look at the `ConfigurationContextId` instead of the `ConfigurationContentId` field. When I fixed this, I started getting only a single result when I expected three. This led me to look at the table association/join logic (see second item below). Corrected code snippet in ConfigurationContentsTable:

```
[Column(Storage = "_configurationContentId", DbType = "BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
public long ConfigurationContentId
{
    get { return _configurationContentId; }
}
```

Second, for all of the EntityRef<> properties with the `[Association(Storage = ...]` attributes, I had the `ThisKey` and `OtherKey` properties reversed. Once I changed the ConfigurationContentsTable to use `ThisKey` and the ConfigurationContextsTable and ConfigurationSectionsTable to use `OtherKey`, I started seeing the expected three distinct results.

Corrected code for ConfigurationContentsTable:

```
[Association(Storage = "_configurationContextsTable", ThisKey = "ConfigurationContextId")]
public ConfigurationContextsTable ConfigurationContextsTable
{
    get { return _configurationContextsTable.Entity; }
    set { _configurationContextsTable.Entity = value; }
}

[Association(Storage = "_configurationSectionsTable", ThisKey = "ConfigurationSectionId")]
public ConfigurationSectionsTable ConfigurationSectionsTable
{
    get { return _configurationSectionsTable.Entity; }
    set { _configurationSectionsTable.Entity = value; }
}
```

Corrected code for ConfigurationContextsTable:

```
[Association(Storage = "_configurationContentsTable", OtherKey = "ConfigurationContextId")]
public ConfigurationContentsTable ConfigurationContentsTable
{
    get { return _configurationContentsTable.Entity; }
    set { _configurationContentsTable.Entity = value; }
}
```

And finally, corrected code for ConfigurationSectionsTable:

```
[Association(Storage = "_configurationContentsTable", OtherKey = "ConfigurationSectionId")]
public ConfigurationContentsTable ConfigurationContentsTable
{
    get { return _configurationContentsTable.Entity; }
    set { _configurationContentsTable.Entity = value; }
}
```

Comment: I ran into this problem because I created my Linq entity classes by hand. I would have avoided this problem entirely had I simply added a "LINQ to SQL Classes" item which creates a dbml design surface on which you can drag your database connection (from server explorer). Do this auto-generates all the entity classes for you.